# Old Local Notifications Firing on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have a set of UILocalNotifications that I am scheduling. They are firing on time and seem to be working fine. However, on occasion, when a **NEW** notification fires there are multiple (sometimes only one) **OLD** notifications that fire along with it.

For example, I schedule a UILocalNotification to take out the trash on Monday at 5pm with no repeat interval. It fires no problem and on time. On Tuesday, I have a UILocalNotification to bring in the trash bins for Tuesday at 5pm, again with no repeat interval. When that one fires, I will see the correct notification for **NOW**, but also below the current notification will be another notification to take the trash out **1 Day Ago**. I have not rescheduled this notification. It appears to be the notification from yesterday.

It is very bizarre and I cannot reproduce it on any sort of consistent basis. I thought that maybe there were some old notifications being added somehow so I added some logic to run through all scheduled notifications and remove any that had a fire date that was in the past but that did not help. Anyone else ever see this problem? Is there some manual clearing of a notification that I need to do when one fires?

EDIT: Added some of the scheduling code

```
//only schedule if the alert date is later than now
if ([AMDateUtil isNowEarlierThanDate:alertDate]) {
    //create the notification and setup some properties
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = alertDate;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotification.alertAction = nil;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    //add the local notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Comment: Please show code of how you created the local notification. The source code can provide clues.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, but managed to fix it by batching our calls to the API. Instead of calling scheduleLocalNotification each time, instead build an array of all notifications you want to be scheduled. Like this:

```
NSMutableArray *notifications = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] mutableCopy];

// add notifications to the mutable array
// same goes for removing notifications

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:notifications];
```

Also make sure you are calling it from the main thread.

Our problems seem to have gone away after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I can think of is to check the repeatInterval of your notifications. It seems that you may want your repeatInterval to be weekly, but the interval seems to be set to daily. To set the repeatInterval to weekly use:

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
```

Perhaps in some places you may be accidentally using

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
```

which repeats once a day.

If that is not the issue, then perhaps if you post some of your code where you schedule the notifications someone could help you. If a notification has a repeat interval of 0 (or not repeating) then you should not have to manually clear it. If the repeat interval is not 0 then you will have to manually clear it to get it to stop repeating.

Comment: I am actually not setting a repeat interval. The example I used was just an example, it isnt necessarily my use case. All of my notifications should not have any repeat intervals. I believe the default is to not repeat correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The issue seems like it probably has something to do with the way the notifications are scheduled. Perhaps you could post some of the scheduling code?